# Javascript string comparison issue with backslash

Tags: javascript, jquery, custom-data-attribute

So I am writing a jquery selector for custom data-xx attribute. What I have as value for this attribute is network path. In my script I am trying to identify the  which was clicked by using value of this attribute in my selector

here is code layout

```
<a data-path="\\network\Dir1\SubDir\SubDir2\file.xml" href="#">Link1</a>
```

and this is my selector which returns nothing.

```
$('a[data-path="\\\\network\\Dir1\\SubDir\\SubDir2\\file.xml"]')
```

only time my selector works is when I just use file name

```
$('a[data-path*="\file.xml"]')
```

I am not sure if there is something wrong with the way am escaping backslash here or in the way am using custom attribute selector.

If I do `$('a#id').data('path')` i get this
 "\network\Dir1\SubDir\SubDir2\file.xml"

thanks

Comment: you'll need to use 4 backslashes for each backslash in your html

Comment: thanks @shiala your comment helped to come with solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in your question comments, you need to use 4 backslahes per backslash in the path:

```
var allLinks = $('a');
var longLink = $('a[data-name="\\\\\\\\network\\\\Dir1\\\\SubDir\\\\SubDir2\\\\file.xml"]');

console.log(" *** links found: ", allLinks.length, longLink.length);
```

Here is a working example: http://plnkr.co/edit/D2w8G7yTaOusG5qwT51x?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

`$('a[data-path="\\\\\\\\network\\\\Dir1\\\\SubDir\\\\SubDir2\\\\file.xml"]')`

**this can be worked , but i don't know it's theory exactly.**

Answer (score 0):

this is what i did eventually. First comment resolved it for me.

```
var path = 'value in html';
path.replace(/\\/g, '\\\\');
$(a'[data-path*="' + path+ '"]');
```